# How to scale the Sprite in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have an image which is 100x100 size. I want to use the whole image but with size of 50x50. When I try to use it, it crops my image and uses only 1/4 of the image (top - left corner).

```
Texture img = new Texture("snake.png");
Sprite mySnake = new Sprite(img);
```

I have tried using `mySnake.setSize(50,50)` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Without seeing your code, my guess is that you need to use `mySnake.draw(batch)` instead of `batch.draw(mySnake)`

Comment: +Xoppa yes you are right, it draws the whole image at 50x50 :) Just one more thing,  I used x and y in batch.draw(mySnake,x ,y). How can I do it using mySnake.draw(batch)?

Comment: nvm, I got it. It's a bit similar. I should have used mySnake.setX(x)

Answer (score 2):

You can scale sprite like:

1. Set the Actor's scale: `sprite.setScale(factor);`
2. With animation: Use Tween engine (LibGDX animation library)
3. Use a custom width in your [SpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) call: `batch.draw(Sprite, float x, float y, float width, float height);`

Comment: Are these alternatives (1 or 2 or 3) or a sequence of things to do in order?